# Create a table in R with header expanding on two columns using xtable or any package

Tags: r, xtable

I want to combine the tables from two dataframes and want to export that table to latex. The table that i want to create looks as follows. Note, the table below is created using excel.

[image]

From xtable in R I was able to export the table for two individual stations. get the following for two stations T1 and T2. How can I combine the output of two stations to get the desired output as above?

Station T1:

```
> stT1
        Observed-modeled |observed-modeled|
Min.          -1.5360000          0.0001891
1st Qu.        0.0002512          0.1633000
Median         0.3593000          0.5390000
Mean           0.8554000          1.0020000
3rd Qu.        1.6470000          1.6470000
Max.           5.5370000          5.5370000

> dput(stT1)
structure(list(`Observed-modeled` = c(-1.536, 0.0002512, 0.3593, 
0.8554, 1.647, 5.537), `|observed-modeled|` = c(0.0001891, 0.1633, 
0.539, 1.002, 1.647, 5.537)), .Names = c("Observed-modeled", 
"|observed-modeled|"), row.names = c("Min.", "1st Qu.", "Median", 
"Mean", "3rd Qu.", "Max."), class = "data.frame")
```

Station T2:

```
> stT2
        Observed-modeled |observed-modeled|
Min.             -2.3740           0.001259
1st Qu.          -1.2280           0.674700
Median           -0.6202           1.101000
Mean             -0.2094           1.085000
3rd Qu.           0.7418           1.413000
Max.              5.0530           5.053000

> dput(stT2)
structure(list(`Observed-modeled` = c(-2.374, -1.228, -0.6202, 
-0.2094, 0.7418, 5.053), `|observed-modeled|` = c(0.001259, 0.6747, 
1.101, 1.085, 1.413, 5.053)), .Names = c("Observed-modeled", 
"|observed-modeled|"), row.names = c("Min.", "1st Qu.", "Median", 
"Mean", "3rd Qu.", "Max."), class = "data.frame")
```

I combined two stations as follows:

```
newstT <- cbind(stT1,stT2)

> newstT
        Observed-modeled |observed-modeled| Observed-modeled |observed-modeled|
Min.          -1.5360000          0.0001891          -2.3740           0.001259
1st Qu.        0.0002512          0.1633000          -1.2280           0.674700
Median         0.3593000          0.5390000          -0.6202           1.101000
Mean           0.8554000          1.0020000          -0.2094           1.085000
3rd Qu.        1.6470000          1.6470000           0.7418           1.413000
Max.           5.5370000          5.5370000           5.0530           5.053000
```

**I was not able to add station T1 and station T2 at the top as shown in the desired figure.**

Comment: You may want to look at `add.to.row` in `?xtable`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `tables` package has a different approach to constructing tables and has a `latex.tabular` method to output the relevant latex.

This will work best if your data is in long form

```
library(tables)

# rbind with rownames as a column 
st <- rbind(
  data.frame(stT1, station = 'T1', what = factor(rownames(stT1), levels = rownames(stT1)), 
             row.names= NULL, check.names = FALSE), 
  data.frame(stT2,station = 'T2',what = factor(rownames(stT2), levels = rownames(stT2)), 
             row.names = NULL,check.names = FALSE)
     )


mytable <- tabular(Heading()*what ~ station*(`Observed-modeled` +`|observed-modeled|`)*Heading()*(identity),data=st)
mytable                                                                                
 ##         station                                                                
 ##         T1                                  T2                                 
 ##         Observed-modeled |observed-modeled| Observed-modeled |observed-modeled|
 ## Min.    -1.5360000       0.0001891          -2.3740          0.001259          
 ## 1st Qu.  0.0002512       0.1633000          -1.2280          0.674700          
 ## Median   0.3593000       0.5390000          -0.6202          1.101000          
 ## Mean     0.8554000       1.0020000          -0.2094          1.085000          
 ## 3rd Qu.  1.6470000       1.6470000           0.7418          1.413000          
 ## Max.     5.5370000       5.5370000           5.0530          5.053000
```

The is a great deal of fine control you have over the outcomes. These are described in the [vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tables/vignettes/tables.pdf).

In the example above you can see that `Heading()` will suppress (or change) the headings for a column while  `identity` is the function which is used to summarize each combination.

And to show that it will create the appropriate tabular latex object (with multicolumns)

```
latex(mytable)


\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
\hline
 & \multicolumn{4}{c}{station} \\ 
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{T1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{T2} \\ 
  & Observed-modeled & |observed-modeled| & Observed-modeled & \multicolumn{1}{c}{|observed-modeled|} \\ 
\hline
Min.  & $-1.5360000$ & $0.0001891$ & $-2.3740$ & $0.001259$ \\
1st Qu.  & $\phantom{-}0.0002512$ & $0.1633000$ & $-1.2280$ & $0.674700$ \\
Median  & $\phantom{-}0.3593000$ & $0.5390000$ & $-0.6202$ & $1.101000$ \\
Mean  & $\phantom{-}0.8554000$ & $1.0020000$ & $-0.2094$ & $1.085000$ \\
3rd Qu.  & $\phantom{-}1.6470000$ & $1.6470000$ & $\phantom{-}0.7418$ & $1.413000$ \\
Max.  & $\phantom{-}5.5370000$ & $5.5370000$ & $\phantom{-}5.0530$ & $5.053000$ \\
\hline 
\end{tabular}
```

As noted above you can remove any column header using `Heading()*` the column in question

eg to remove "station" from the first row (as a header for all columns)

```
tabular(Heading()*what ~ Heading()*station*(`Observed-modeled` +`|observed-modeled|`)*Heading()*(identity),data=st)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing to the tables package. Your approach does what I am looking for.

Comment: Is it possible to get rid of `station` on the top row ? Rest is perfect. Instead of two lines `station` and then `T1` and `T2`, I want only `T1` and `T2`. I could manually delete the line in latex code, but I am using knitr and would be helpful if I could delete with code.

Comment: @Jdbaba -- using `Heading()*station` -- see the edited answer.

Comment: One thing I noticed is when `tables` package processes `mytable` using `latex(mytable)` in the above example, it doesn't automatically change the `|` to `$|$` . Because of this `-observed-modeled -`is obtained when processed by latex or knitr. Is there any workaround for this other than manual edit ? xtable automatically places dollar sign around `|` but tables doesn't. Am I missing something ?

Comment: True -- you can manually do this using the `sanitize` function within `print.xtable`

Comment: The problem is not with xtable but the problem is with `tables` package. We can do everything that you did above using `xtable` package, is that what you mean ?

Comment: No, extract the `sanitize` function from `print.xtable` and run that over the appropriate part of the `tabular` object. Not ideal. but would work